# How to exclude line height for visibility hidden td elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html-table

My goal is to set 'AutoWrap' `td` elements in my grid for visible `td` elements.

For a specific purpose, I have set `visibility:hidden` and `width:0px` to hide `td` elements for IE8 browser.

It makes the visible `td` elements height based on hidden autowrapped `td` elements.

Is there any other way on how to exclude hidden elements height for the visible `td` elements without using `display:none`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tNndY/)

Comment: Any issues in using `display: none`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: i have faced several issues regarding display:none in IE8 browser so i changed it to visibility:hidden and width:0px to hide columns.

Answer (score 1):

As you commented, you are redundant to use `display: none;` and if you want to achieve this by only CSS, the best you can do is, use the below CSS rule

```
table tr td:first-child {
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tNndY/4/)

> Note: You are using `border="1" cellspacing="1"` which is resulting in
>   a thick border to the left of the table.